# Android Sql Database not saving data

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I'm using a library called AndroidSqlDB for my project , i have set it up properly as per the documentation but i still face an issue that i couldn't solve of anyone could help solving it , thank you in advance .

- This is the library i'm using

```
implementation 'com.github.p32929:AndroidEasySQL-Library:1.4.1'
```

- This is the code to save data in db

```
val easyDB =   EasyDB.init(this,"ITEMS_DB")
                    .setTableName("CART_TABLE")
                    .addColumn(Column("item_id", *arrayOf("text","unique")))
                    .addColumn(Column("item_title", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("item_category", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("item_price_each", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("item_price", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("item_quantity", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("product_delivery_fee", *arrayOf("text", "not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("country", *arrayOf("text", "not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("city", *arrayOf("text", "not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("address", *arrayOf("text", "not null")))
                    .addColumn(Column("state", *arrayOf("text", "not null")))


            val isAdded = easyDB
                    .addData("item_id",1)
                    .addData("item_title",model.productName)
                    .addData("item_category",model.productCategory)
                    .addData("item_price_each",model.productPrice)
                    .addData("item_price",totalPrice.toString())
                    .addData("item_quantity",itemIndex.toString())
                    .addData("product_delivery_fee",model.productDeliveryFee)
                    .addData("country",country)
                    .addData("city",city)
                    .addData("address",address)
                    .addData("state",state)
                    .doneDataAdding()
```

- this is the error

```
E/SQLiteLog: (21) API called with NULL prepared statement
    (21) misuse at line 78396 of [0c55d17973]
D/TAG: Exception not an error (code 0 SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: One of your variables is null.  Your columns are set up to be not null.  Either the data or your schema is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try to figure out if there is any null values and update you .

Comment: I have found out that there are some null values , now they are not null , all values are checked and none of them is null but still shows the same issue , any idea why ? thank you